# IF Condition in variable in SSIS Package

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl

I have a folder in Cloud with some files and I have an SSIS Package that upload these file to SQL. I have also two variables on my SSIS package: `start_date` and `end_date`.

[image]

Basically, I would like to do that:

- If start_date is empty then the SSIS should upload files since last uploaded.
- If start_date is not empty the SSIS should upload the file from start_date to end_date.
  I have a variable that configures the files that SSIS needs to upload. I have a problem here:

[image]

I don´t know I can set up this step, because when start_date is empty the SSIS gives an error message

Comment: You can use SSIS's REPLACENULL function to form a valid date string (use a dummy value like 1900-01-01 for the NULL value) and do all the work in SQL.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the following syntax:

```
IF '" + (DT_WSTR,10)REPLACENULL(@[$Package::start_date],"") + "' <> ''
```